I’d like to understand why this code runs so slowly
I've written a code, maybe an easy coding test.
(details under)
boxers play matches
better man always win
ex)
if A boxer is better than B, A always wins B
if C boxer is better than A, C always wins A, B
So, always (C > A > B), never (C > A > B > C) things.

After the competition ends, some match results are missing.
Given the results you have, determine how many boxers can be definitively ranked.
*constrains
i)  1 <= boxers <= 100.
ii)  1 <= results.size() <= 4500, results contains match_data.
iii) match_data [A, B] means (A defeated B).
iV) no contradictions in the data: if [A,B] exist, [B,A] does not.

----------------------------------------------------------------------

N of boxer                       results                          answer

    5             [[4, 3], [4, 2], [3, 2], [1, 2], [2, 5]]      2

-----------------------------------------------------------------------

                        [[  explain  ]]

In this situation, u can construct two rank-chains.
4 > 3 > 2 > 5
1 > 2 > 5
Here, 2, 5 can confirm their rank 4th, 5th respectively
But, 4, 3, 1 can't confirm their relative rank due to missing data.
Thus, answer is 2;
my code below
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int win = 0;
int lose = 1;

int solution(int n, vector<vector<int>> results) {

    queue<pair<int, int>> q;

    vector<vector<vector<int>>> Graph(n, vector<vector<int>>(2));

    vector<int> rating = vector(n,0);

    vector<vector<vector<int>>> List(n, vector<vector<int>>(2, vector<int>(n, 0)));


    for(int match=0; match < results.size(); match++){

        int winner = results[match][win]-1;
        int loser = results[match][lose]-1;

        Graph[winner][win].push_back(loser);
        Graph[loser][lose].push_back(winner);
    
    }

    for(int index=0; index<n; index++){
    
        if(Graph[index][win].size() == 0 && Graph[index][lose].size() == 0) return 0;
    
        if(Graph[index][win].size() == 0){
            for(int i=0; i<Graph[index][lose].size(); i++){
                q.push({Graph[index][lose][i], index});
            }
            while(!q.empty()){
                auto [winner, loser] = q.front();
                q.pop();
            
                if(List[winner][win][loser]==0){
                    List[winner][win][loser] = 1;
                    rating[winner]++;
                }
            
            
                for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
                    if(List[loser][win][j] == 1 && List[winner][win][j] == 0){
                        List[winner][win][j] = 1;
                        rating[winner]++;
                    }
                }
            
                for(int j=0; j<Graph[winner][lose].size(); j++){
                    q.push({Graph[winner][lose][j], winner});
                }
            }
        }
    
        if(Graph[index][lose].size() == 0){
            for(int i=0; i<Graph[index][win].size(); i++){
                q.push({Graph[index][win][i], index});
            }
         
            while(!q.empty()){
                auto [loser, winner] = q.front();
                q.pop();
                
                if(List[loser][lose][winner]==0){
                    List[loser][lose][winner] = 1;
                    rating[loser]++;
                }
                
            
                for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
                    if(List[winner][lose][j] == 1 && List[loser][lose][j] == 0){
                        List[loser][lose][j] = 1;
                        rating[loser]++;
                    }
                }
            
                for(int j=0; j<Graph[loser][win].size(); j++){
                    q.push({Graph[loser][win][j], loser});
                }
            }
        }
    }

    int answer = 0;
    for(int index=0; index<n; index++){
        //cout << rating[index] << ", ";
        if(rating[index]==n-1){
            answer++;
        }
    }

    return answer;

}

My code works, and I expected that complexity of my code is O(n^2+n⋅m)
<< n = boxer number, m = results.size() >>
When given a lot of data, it still works but takes too long time.
I found that Floyd-Warshall Algorithm works much better.
Even so, I really want to know why my code takes so much time and what its actual time complexity is.

Thank you for taking the time to read and help.


Have you profiled your code to see where the time is actually being spent?

I’ve never thought about that, and honestly, I’m not sure how to.
Thanks! I’ll go look for a method to check.

Have you enabled the compilers optimizer (-O2 or -O3 for g++ or clang++)?

Not related to time-complexity, but two observations affecting the performance of your code:
First, how you passing the data:
int solution(int n, vector<vector<int>> results) {

This creates an unnecessary copy of the input-data. Better to pass by const&. Doesn't affect the time of the main loop, but creates avoidable allocations at the start.
Second, some of your data-structures can be improved:
vector<vector<vector<int>>> Graph(n, vector<vector<int>>(2));

As some of your data-sizes are unknown, having some nested vectors make sense. However, the second vector in the chain is always accessed via either 0 or 1, so it can be replaced by an array without requiring modifying the rest of the code:
vector<array<vector<int>, 2>> Graph(n);

Has the nice side-effect of also making the initialization a bit less clunky. But mainly, it will remove one indirection in accessing the data, as well as some unnecessary allocations. The shame should apply to "List" too.
So in general, it's a good idea to use fixed-sized arrays when you know the size upfront, instead of vector (which is designed to hold varying sizes, but pays for that with slightly less optimal memory layout and allocations).

Thanks for your detailed advice. I hope your work goes well too.

First, create a forest graph with the distinct chains that you have and for each chain, store the address of the chain in a map whose key is the node index, the value is a vector of vectors of int, so a vector of ranking chains. This is the build up, where you will end up having a map<int, vector<vector<int>>>. Check the number of keys of the map. If there are less keys than n, then none of the boxers are fully ranked.
Otherwise, loop the Map and in each iteration, create a set, initialized with the given node and loop the vector<vector<int>> chains and each chain inside, to see whether the items are already in the set and add each element that's not in the set into the set, until either the set has n elements, in which case the node is fully ranked, or you reached the end of the search in which case you check whether set has n elements, in which case the node is fully ranked, otherwise the node is not fully ranked.
Your slowness is because you

loop index from 0 to n

build a queue of wins/losses
loop your queue

loop j from 0 to n
loop your queue again





So instead of this, do a full graph traversal starting from people who only lost (or only won, the direction is up to you to determine) and build distinct chains as well as a map. This will make your algorithm more efficient I think.

I really appreciate your help. I will review my work as you suggested.

@AK1557 happy to help!
